Angular PrimeNG modify p-button, p-inputSwitch styles
How to modify PrimeNG's p-button, p-inputSwitch styles if ng::deep is deprecated?

::ng-deep is not deprecated, it's just not recommended. https://angular.dev/guide/components/styling#ng-deep

You have to add a class to scope the CSS, then add the styles to the global styles file in the angular project.
SCSS:
.custom-button > button {
  background: rgb(46, 82, 33) ;
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(46, 82, 33, 1) 22%,
    rgba(104, 157, 79, 1) 100%
  ) ;
}

.custom-switch {
  .p-inputswitch .p-inputswitch-slider {
    background: black;
  }
}

HTML:
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
  <p-button label="Submit" class="custom-button" />
  <p-inputSwitch class="custom-switch" />
</div>

Stackblitz Demo

I have updated to PrimeNG 17 + Angular 18 and I found how to style buttons without ::ng-deep:
HTML:
<p-button pButton label="Submit" class="custom-button" />

or
<button pButton label="Submit" class="custom-button"></button>

SCSS:
.custom-button {
  background: green;
}

It works for me.
